# Select distinct and largest

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a dataset like this:

```
ColA|ColB
---------
A   |1
A   |2
A   |3
B   |1
B   |2
```

And I need to develop a query returning distinct over `ColA` and max over `ColB`, like this:

```
A|3
B|2
```

But I can't seem to wrap my head around how to approach it.  Pretty sure I  need nested queries.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `MAX()`.

Comment: D'oh!  My sql is so rusty!  Thanks @GordonLinoff - `select cola, max(colb) from table group by cola`

Answer (score 0):

As basically answered by @GordonLinoff - `SELECT ColA, MAX(ColB) FROM table GROUP BY ColA;`  Lol oops.

Comment: @Parfait Yeah I know, I suck, hence all the sarcasm and self-deprecation.  I'm a programmer not a DBA - I crawled through the official sqlite docs and google searches for 30 minutes before asking but couldn't figure out how to phrase the question.